# Como atualizar automaticamente o Valor Total de um Pedido baseado nos itens do pedido em Firebird com SP e Trigger

Tags: firebird

Alguém na área? Preciso de uma ajuda simples em SP e Trigger no Firebird. Meu conhecimento é bem limitado.

Tenho 03 tabelas aqui PEDIDO, ITEM_PEDIDO e PRODUTO

Em Pedido tenho o campo Valor_Total do pedido que é igual soma dos itens do pedido multiplicado pela quantidade.

Valor_Pedido = Qtde * Valor_Unitario

O valor unitário está na tabela produtos. Por isso preciso fazer um Select retornando todos os itens de um pedido com Inner Join em Produtos pra descobrir o valor_unitario.

Ao adicionar, excluir ou alterar um item no pedido, o campo VALOR_TOTAL no Pedido deve ser recalculado.
Posso fazer fica aplicação, fazer um update no banco e boas. Mas gostaria de deixar o banco fazer sozinho.

Criei um Stored Procedure que retorna o valor total de cada item.
E agora desejo fazer uma Trigger no Item_Pedido que ao ser disparada, chama a SP, soma os valores salva no campo VALOR_TOTAL.

Ou, se alguém tiver uma forma até mais fácil, melhor ainda.

Obs: "Ignorem meus erros, eu sou nível abaixo de fraldinha em banco de dados, kkkk"

Valeu

Minha Stored Procedure

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER "_TG_UPDATE_PEDIDO" FOR ITEM_PEDIDO
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE POSITION 0
AS
  DECLARE VARIABLE TOT DOUBLE PRECISION;
  DECLARE VARIABLE PED INTEGER;
begin
  FOR
    SELECT VALOR_TOTAL_ITEM FROM PED_VALOR_TOTAL(53) INTO :TOT DO
    UPDATE PEDIDO SET VALOR_TOTAL = (VALOR_TOTAL + :TOT);
    /*WHERE ID_PEDIDO = NEW.ID_PEDIDO;*/
end

create or alter procedure PED_VALOR_TOTAL (
    ID_PEDIDO integer)
returns (
    VALOR_TOTAL_ITEM double precision)
as
begin
  FOR
    SELECT (IT.QTDE * PD.VLR_UNITARIO)
    FROM
      ITEM_PEDIDO IT
      INNER JOIN PRODUTO PD
      ON IT.ID_PRODUTO = PD.ID
    WHERE
      IT.ID_PEDIDO = :ID_PEDIDO
    INTO
      VALOR_TOTAL_ITEM
    DO SUSPEND;
end^

SET TERM ; ^
```

Answer (score -2):

Puxa, acabei recebendo a resposta em outro grupo, então ai vai a resposta.
Obrigado.

Obs. Matei a SP, nem precisa.

```
SET TERM ^ ;



CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER "_TG_UPDATE_PEDIDO" FOR ITEM_PEDIDO
ACTIVE AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE POSITION 0
AS
begin
  UPDATE PEDIDO SET 
    VALOR_TOTAL = COALESCE(
      (
        SELECT
          SUM(IT.QTDE * PD.VLR_UNITARIO)
        FROM
          ITEM_PEDIDO IT
          INNER JOIN PRODUTO PD
          ON IT.ID_PRODUTO = PD.ID
        WHERE
          IT.ID_PEDIDO = COALESCE(NEW.ID_PEDIDO, OLD.ID_PEDIDO)
       ), 0)
    WHERE
      ID = COALESCE(NEW.ID_PEDIDO, OLD.ID_PEDIDO);
end
^


SET TERM ; ^
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).